# SSH from Linux computer into GUI of windows computer?

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, remote-control

Basically I want to store my Windows system somewhere remote and use SSH (or any other protocol that would work) on Linux (specifically a raspberry pi) to access the entire desktop GUI on the Windows machine.

I have had a look in on the internet but I can't find any clues to this myself, can anyone here help me?

Comment: Are you dead-set on using SSH, or would another protocol be acceptable?

Comment: Any protocol that is fast enough would be perfectly acceptable, asking for SSH was through to my own inexperience with any other. (I have use remote-control systems like Teamviewer and LogMeIn but they are horrendously slow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [rdesktop](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-remote-desktop-for-controlling-windows-xp-desktop.html):

> Fortunately, Linux has rdesktop utility. It is a client for remote desktop protocol (RDP), used in a number of Microsoft products including Windows NT Terminal Server, Windows 2000 Server, Windows XP and Windows 2003 / 2008 Server. You do not need to install VNC server. All you need is rdesktop client on Linux or BSD workstation.

Comment: The [freerdp](http://www.freerdp.com/) fork of rdesktop is probably a better choice these days.  It has better support the newer versions of Windows.

Comment: @Zoredache It probably is.  I've personally never had a need to use it, so I always recommended rdesktop.  Thank you for the updated information.

Comment: Is the communications path secure using rdesktop/freerdp?  I believe that was part of the question too.

Comment: See here for security: http://serverfault.com/questions/257083/how-secure-is-remote-desktop-connection.  While SSH is going to be more secure, OP did not specify security requirements.

Answer (score 3):

If your Windows is "Pro" version or "better" than RDP will work. "Home" versions do not have the server-side. So you will need something like VNC.
Also RDP does not allow for a shared desktop, so if you want to share the desktop with the local user then again VNC is to be recommended.

Suggest tightvnc for the Windows server side. There are several client side VNC implementations for a Linux box as as well at least a couple of RDP clients (rdesktop, freerdp) if you go that route.

You will, of course, need to forward ports to the server if it's behind a NAT firewall.

Comment: The "home" version has been renamed as just "Windows 8". There is a "Windows 8 Professional".

Comment: See: http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-8/remote-desktop-faq

Comment: Ah I see, well I am using Pro version at the moment anyhow. :3

Comment: Remember that VNC or TightVNC offers no communications encryption as SSH does.